# Use ng-template in the child component from the parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I have the following component for render a list of options. `optionsList` input gets a list that needs to be rendered with a custom format provided from the `item` input.

**list-box.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let option of optionsList; index as it">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="item"></ng-container>
</div>
```

**list-box.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-box',
  templateUrl: './list-box.component.html'
})
export class ListBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('item') public item!:TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input('optionsList') optionsList:any[]=[];
  ...
}
```

**Then**, in a parent component I have a template that contains the format for render each item, and send it to the list-box component for the task:

**In the parent.component.html**

```
<ng-template let-option pTemplate="item" #item>
  <label>{{it}}: {{option.name}}</label>
</ng-template>

<app-list-box
  [optionsList]="[{'name': '...'}, ...]"
  [item]="item">
</app-list-box>
```

This code obviously doesn't work, it shows the error that `option` and `it` don't exist in the parent.

The question is, **How can I send a particular format to render each item in the child component?.**

I can use a specific format in the child component, but if the list of items has other type of items with different fields, then the list-box component is not useful, and I would need to create another specific component or map the content from the list to set the names of the required fields, but it is not desired.

> **P.S.** For this writing, I simplified the code using ngfor, because in practical terms it is what I require. I don't want to put the ngFor in the parent to set all the items there, the sample code is a simulation of an imported module that I want to customize.

Comment: Please check if my answer is satisfactory within your required context, if you have doubts about what was done, please comment so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, both answers work for what I was looking to do: customize the primeng listbox module, to work in the background with my own style, but I couldn't due to the situation explained in the problem. Once again, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account the following code:

**parent.component.html**:

```
<ng-template let-option pTemplate="item" #item>
  <label>{{it}}: {{option.name}}</label>
</ng-template>

<app-list-box
  [optionsList]="[{'name': '...'}, ...]"
  [item]="item">
</app-list-box>
```

1. ✓ I can see that the parameter `let-option` is implicit, this is because it is not being assigned to a specific element of the context. (example: `let example="something"`) [Valid]
2. The variable "it" has not been defined, which can generate an error. [Invalid]

---

Taking into account that {{ it }} means the current position of the loop, can be done as follows:

**parent.component.html**:

```
<ng-template let-option let-it="index" #item>
  <label>{{it}}: {{option.name}}</label>
</ng-template>

<app-list-box
  [optionsList]="[{'name': '...'}, ...]"
  [item]="item">
</app-list-box>
```

**list-box.component.html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of optionsList; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item; context: {$implicit: option, index: i}"></ng-container>
</div>
```

It is important to note that:

$implicit -> will be assigned to `let-option` 
index -> will be assigned to `let-it`

Test demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sea-diiu5x?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the context to the `ngTemplateOutlet`

```
<div *ngFor="let option of optionsList; index as it">
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="item"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ option: option, it: it }">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And change `ng-template` to receive this parameter

```
<ng-template let-option="option" let-it="it" pTemplate="item" #item>
  <label>{{it}}: {{option.name}}</label>
</ng-template>
```